# How to permanently reset my $PATH?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, shell, path

I was trying to add something to $PATH and it went totally wrong. I now can't run any commands such as `ls`. I've looked at this answer (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11745/reset-your-path-variable) and used the following lines:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

These lines fix the problem temorarily; however, when I restart terminal it seems to forget these changes.

How do I permanently reset my $PATH?

I'm running the most recent version of Mountain Lion.

Thanks

Comment: Where did you try adding something to your $PATH? Which file did you change?

Comment: I think it was .bash_profile but it may have been .profile...I'm very inexperienced with terminal

Comment: Then just open these files and remove whatever line begins with `PATH=` or `export PATH=`.

Comment: It was either .bashrc or .profile or .bash_profile. Check all three.

Comment: also asked on [askdifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/79306/7057)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously have a malformatted line somewhere in one of your shell configuration files that are read when the Terminal starts Bash. This is either `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, depending on which you used. In OS X, `.bashrc` isn't read unless you've explicitly sourced it from one of these other files.

To be able to use the commands without setting a `$PATH`, simply call them by their full location.

If you know that there's nothing else in the files you need, delete them:

```
/bin/rm ~/.bash_profile
/bin/rm ~/.profile
```

If not, open them in TextEdit, for example, and remove the offending lines with `PATH=`:

```
/usr/bin/open -a TextEdit ~/.bash_profile
/usr/bin/open -a TextEdit ~/.profile
```

If you'd like to use a command line editor, you can do that as well:

```
/usr/bin/vim ~/.bash_profile
/usr/bin/nano ~/.bash_profile
# et cetera
```

Comment: Thank you so much!`/bin/rm ~/.bash_profile` worked!

Comment: You're welcome! In the future, if you're trying out things in your PATH, you could always run a second Terminal tab in the background in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This was also asked on [apple stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79306/how-to-reset-path/100303#100303) and the accepted answer here is dangerous.

Rather than just removing the `.bash_profile` better to do as the commenters suggest and fix the PATH definition. The problem is that you defined it from "scratch" first, overwriting all previous definitions (including where to find `ls`, and others).

You define the path in .bash_profile by setting a new variable equal to the old one (read with $PATH) plus what you want to add:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/myspecialfolder:$HOME/bin
```

Note that you can't have any spaces on either side of the equal sign. I am also leaving out `{}`, which you might need if there are spaces in your folder names.

Comment: I *did* say "If you know that there's nothing else in the files you need, delete them". You might want to read through it again, because I mentioned a few ways of editing the file to remove the wrong statements.

Comment: Yes, I know you caution against it, but that was the take-home that the OP posted on the other site: "Solved it: `rm ~/.bash_profile`". I am just trying to point out the source of their original problem in the PATH definition, before recommending amputation ;^)

Comment: @Slhck I see what you were trying to do, and re-added an up vote, but I think a more general fix would be to define an emergency PATH in the terminal as `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin`

Comment: Yes, that would work as an emergency solution, but you'd still need to do something with the profile to fix it. I think the OP knows that the source of the problem was the faulty definition, and since they didn't use the `.bash_profile` for anything else (as they admitted they were inexperienced with navigating the terminal), I recommended deletion.