# How do I prevent $PATH from resetting itself each time?

Tags: bash, terminal, shell, osx-mountain-lion, path

I'm having difficulty setting up the PATH on my macbook pro.

I followed this [link](http://architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#.Ua1HfmQjouE) to modify my path variable.

Each time I start a new terminal I get a PATH pointing towards

```
/Applications/eclipse/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin
```

Even though the `.bash_profile` is as follows

```
EXPORT PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

And `/etc/paths` has the following content

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/Applications/eclipse/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin
```

I did try to look at this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/538400/how-to-permanently-reset-my-path) as well but it didn't help much either

Comment: I'm not sure why your bashrc exports PATH three times, but a sub issue you have is that the third export makes the first two useless; it includes both dirs they add, and it forgets to have the `:$PATH`, removing the previous contents.

Comment: Could you suggest how I should modify the files, so as to correct the problem? N00b here.

Comment: You can edit it with your editor of choice. `vim`, `emacs`, etc. Or, as you are on mac, if you want a gui editor: `open -a TextEdit ~/.bashrc`

Comment: And what contents do I put in `bashrc`?I dont think I have that file as of now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your shell is sh. [OS X's /bin/sh is a version of bash](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89311/are-bash-bourne-and-korn-shells-compiled-into-one-binary-in-osx/89327#89327) where the main difference is that POSIX mode is enabled by default. It doesn't read ~/.bash_profile for login shells either. From `man bash`:

> If bash is invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well. When invoked as an interactive login shell, or a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first attempts to read and execute commands from /etc/profile and ~/.profile, in that order.

So you could use ~/.profile instead of ~/.bash_profile, but you'll probably just want to change the shell to a normal bash:

- Set Startup > "Shells open with" to "Default login shell" if it's set to something else
- Run `chsh -s /bin/bash` if the default login shell was changed

Notes about the comment thread in David X's answer:

- Symlinking /bin/bash to /bin/sh wouldn't help. The /bin/bash and /bin/sh binaries are almost identical, but the behavior depends on the name bash was invoked with.
- Terminal and iTerm open new shells as login shells by default, so for example bash reads ~/.bash_profile but not ~/.bashrc.
- Normal user accounts are not included in /etc/passwd on OS X.

Comment: This sounds pretty much right, +1.

Comment: Works great! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure PATH needs to be set in .bashrc instead of .*profile.
Try putting this in your .bash_profile (replacing the `export PATH` lines):

```
if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
fi
```

and this in your .bashrc:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

Comment: Did you mix them both ?

Comment: Did you mean the first snippet goes into `.bashrc` (which I dont have at the moment) and the second one in `.bash_profile` ?

Comment: `.bash_profile` is run when bash starts as a login shell. (You probably don't do that, but it's a good idea to make sure it works anyway.) `.bashrc` is run when bash starts as a non-login shell, for example when you start a GUI terminal emulator (aka a xterm).

Comment: @KodeSeeker, no the first snippet goes in `.bash_profile` and the second goes in `.bashrc`. I'll edit to make that more clear.

Comment: Sadly it does not work .here are the contents of my `.bashrc`- http://pastebin.com/jiQ9i5q0 and my `.bash_profile`-http://pastebin.com/jPu1DfYm

Comment: @KodeSeeker, can you post the result of `echo +$PATH+`? (In a fresh terminal, I mean.)

Comment: That gives `+/Applications/eclipse/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin+`

Comment: @KodeSeeker, could you post the output of `which bash`, the CMD column of `ps` and the first line from `bash --version`? Also try putting `echo test` in your .bashrc. It sounds like you might have some non-bash shell installed. Other than than that I can't think of anything.

Comment: The output of `which bash` :`/bin/bash`. 
The output of `ps` :`PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1800 ttys000    0:00.01 -sh
 1815 ttys001    0:00.01 -sh
` And output of `bash --version`:`GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: Ok, so it's running `sh` instead of `bash`. Can you try `ls /bin/sh` and `grep $USER /etc/passwd`? The last field of the latter is what *should* be your shell and I'm guessing `/bin/sh` is a symlink to something other than bash. Also if the field immediately after your user name isnt a x, don't post that field.

Comment: The result of `ls /bin/sh` is :`/bin/sh` and `grep $USER /etc/passwd` returns nothing. Quite frankly I'm just posting the results of whatever you are asking for.

Comment: @KodeSeeker, I think that your default shell (which on unix is the last field of of a entry in /etc/passwd) is set to something other than bash ... actually can you try `/bin/bash`, and then, at the new bash promt, try `echo +$PATH+` and `ps` again?

Comment: Thanks for getting back so patiently. Here's the output
`LM-SCF-00871773:~vvm$ /bin/bash 
test
bash-3.2$ echo +$PATH+
+/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin+
bash-3.2$ ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1800 ttys000    0:00.01 -sh
 1815 ttys001    0:00.02 -sh
 1972 ttys001    0:00.01 /bin/bash
bash-3.2$ 
`

Comment: @KodeSeeker, no problem, thanks for the information. Anyway, there's three ways to fix your problem: The quick and dirty way is to do `sudo ln -sfT bash /bin/sh` which will cause bash to be run from sh (do `ls -al /bin/sh` first and make a note of the old target of sh). The proper way is to find out where your default shell is set and change it to /bin/bash. The other proper way is to figure out which shell you're using and look up the rc files for it. If you need help with the latter two you should probably ask another question though.

Comment: I tried `sudo ln -sfT bash /bin/sh` . I got an error saying `ln: illegal option -- T
usage: ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file [target_file]
       ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file ... target_dir
       link source_file target_file`.. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try `cd /bin` then `ls -l sh` then `sudo ln -sf bash /bin/sh` (and post the output from ls).

Comment: Here you go :`LM-SCF-00871773:~ vvm$ cd /bin/
LM-SCF-00871773:bin vvm$ sudo ln -sf bash /bin/sh
Password:
LM-SCF-00871773:bin vvm$ ls
[  df  launchctl pwd  tcsh
bash  domainname link  rcp  test
cat  echo  ln  rm  unlink
chmod  ed  ls  rmdir  wait4path
cp  expr  mkdir  sh  zsh
csh  hostname mv  sleep
date  kill  pax  stty
dd  ksh  ps  sync`

Comment: @KodeSeeker, did that work? New terminal launchs fine &c?

Comment: Nope it doesnt work in the new terminal. It only works in the earlier terminal because I did an `export PATH` manually

Comment: @KodeSeeker, you'll probably need to try one of the proper ways then; sorry I couldn't help better.

Answer (score 0):

just have a single entry there ..... the third one over writes everything ...

```
export PATH=.:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Doesnt work . I still get `sudo` command not found when I start a new terminal

Comment: It's a bad idea to put `.` in your PATH, and it's a *really* bad idea to put it at the start. Doing so allows any directory with a executable file named `sudo` to potentially take over your computer (eg that that tarball you just downloaded). It also causes less severe problems with other commands that don't expect to type your password into.

Comment: @KodeSeeker, case in point.